# Replace images with jQuery in userscript

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

I'm currently working on a userscript, but I have a problem.
I'm trying to replace an image with another one.

I thought I could do it this way:

```
$(".subforumicon.ajax_mark_read").each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/http:\/\/x\.hackforums\.net\/images\/modern_pl\/minion.gif/g, "http://megaviews.net/hf/designcostumizer/themes/green/minion.png"));
});
```

However, this will do nothing. When I paste this code in the javascript console, it just displays all img-tags with this picture:
[image: Javascript Console]

I don't want to replace everything by using `$("body").html()`, as this can cause problems with the website (somehow).
Before I started working with jQuery, I used `document.body.innerHTML`, what caused issues on the page, but with `document.getElementById()` it worked, so I don't think it was my fault. ;)

I'm quite new to jQuery, so could somebody please explain me why my above code doesn't work?

Comment: You're probably looking for `$('img').prop('src', function(_,src) { return src.replace('old', 'new'); });`

Comment: @adeneo Well... okay, that was easy. It works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because the selected elements are `img` and there is nothing below the img elements.. as .html() selects or sets the INSIDE content (like innerHTML). not outerHTML so you cannot access the attributes of the img element itself by this mean.

You should work on the img's src attribute as already proposed in other posts.

Answer (score 0):

Use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-functionindex--oldPropertyValue)

you need `$('img')` as you are changing image `src` only.

so replace `img` attribute `src` only.

why traverse through all full `html` you need to focus on `src` property only.

```
$('img').prop('src', function (_, old_src) {
    return old_src.replace(/http:\/\/x\.hackforums\.net\/images\/modern_pl\/minion.gif/g, "http://megaviews.net/hf/designcostumizer/themes/green/minion.png");
});
```

---

or better if you want to change all `images` attribute `src`

```
$('img').prop('src','http://x.hackforums.net/images/modern_pl/minion.gif');
```